# How to add a filename attribute to an object?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell I am running the following pipeline:

`$names = Get-ChildItem -Name`

`$a = foreach($name in $names) {Get-ChildItem $name | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum}`

I would like to add the $name variable as a property object and have attempted to do so using `Add-Member` like so:

`$a = foreach($name in $names) {Get-ChildItem $name | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $name}`

However the result is nothing and I can't understand why nor achieve my desired output.

Comment: Whats your desired output?

Comment: Add `-PassThru` to the `Add-Member` call: `... |Add-Member ... -PassThru`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I would mark this as the correct answer. How did you know?

Comment: How did he know? https://i.imgflip.com/3580r4.jpg

Comment: Yeah, @TheMadTechnician is spot on, I used the dark powers of "experience and observation" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, add the `-PassThru` switch parameter to `Add-Member` in order to make it output the (modified) input object:

```
$a = foreach($name in $names) {
    $measurement = Get-ChildItem $name | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum 
    $measurement | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $name -PassThru
}
```